# Why Does my Android MediaPlayer need permission to play music directly from device

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an Android Music playing application that plays audio files from the device itself.

The application plays the audio OK, however I always receive this error in my LOGCAT output

```
MediaPlayer: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10285 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

I configured the MediaPlayer as follows:-

```
   mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(buildOnPreparedListener());
   mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(buildOnErrorListener());
```

I guess its because I have set AudioStreamType as STREAM_MUSIC, what other choice do I have?

I do not want to ask my users to Allow Internet access when they do not need to do this>

I do not like these errors appearing in my LOGCAT.

Do I have any options to configure a MediaPlayer to play "local" audio files without generating these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ringtone and RingtoneManager to play local files

```
RingTone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), SoundUri);
ringtone.play();
```

MediaPlayer was created to provide playback of audio/video files and streams so they need android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission for streams.